# Is onDestroy() method needed to put in every activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

Is it always needed to conserve phone memory? I'd like to know so I can optimize my android application that I'm currently developing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is onDestroy() method needed to put in every activity?

No. There is a default implementation of `onDestroy()` that you inherit, that will handle cleaning up stuff created by the activity itself. You override `onDestroy()` if there are additional things that you created that you wish to clean up, and you determine that waiting until `onDestroy()` is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity is always extending system `Activity` class, which implements all "core" methods as well (and you usually override `onCreate()` as you simply need to set some stuff up like Activity's layout. So unless you do something more sophisticated (like i.e. you register some listeners in `onCreate()`) you do not need writing own `onDestroy()`. In case of said listeners, you should unregister your listener in `onDestroy()` otherwise other code would try to talk to object that no longer exists and crash will appear. Mind that if you will be creating own `onDestroy()` implementation, you have to call `super.onDestroy()` as **last** thing in your implementation (this is generic rule when you extend contructor/destructor alike methods).

Comment: Thanks. When you said listener, is setOnClickListener included in it? Yeah I know it's obvious I just want to be clear

Comment: It was just example because by registering listener you provide reference to your object - you are telling the other code, simply let me know if anything happens. But since this is code, trying to "tell" someone who does not exists ends in "teller"'s crash. But if you refer to OnClickListener assigned to i.e. buttons in layout of your activity then you do not need to unregister these because system knows you are going down and will not try to send anything to you.